# check ethereum wallet on via api blockchain.info

Tags: python, api, python-3.5, blockchain, blockchain.info-api

i am using https://blockchain.info/ api For checking my balance i use this link :

```
https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/16****
```

Is there something similar for ethereum wallet ?
i want to know sender's address and history of my ethereum wallet in blockchain info

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you're looking for an api to check balance of ethereum accounts ?

Check this : https://etherscan.io/apis

Answer (score 0):

[Amberdata.io](https://amberdata.io) has an [API](https://amberdata.io/pricing) with [a bunch of data on addresses](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference/addresses#get-all-addresses). Something unique is that they have Historical Account Balances, as well as, the ability to [list all transactions by address](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference/addresses#get-address-transactions).

Here's an example response from the `addresses/:hash/statistics` endpoint:

```js
curl \
    -X "GET" \
    -H "accept: application/json" \
    -H "x-api-key: <api_key>" \
    "https://web3api.io/api/v1/addresses/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d/statistics"
```

Response:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "title": "OK",
  "description": "Successful request",
  "payload": {
    "balance": "43625340634292316919",
    "balanceIn": "2.714245071508029334975e+22",
    "balanceOut": "2.7098825374446001032831e+22",
    "addressType": "contract",
    "contractTypes": [
      "ERC721"
    ],
    "decimals": "0",
    "name": "CryptoKitties",
    "numHolders": "72506",
    "numTokens": "1421403",
    "numTransfers": "1356726",
    "symbol": "CK",
    "totalSupply": "1421403.0000000000000000",
    "totalValueUSD": null,
    "unitValueUSD": null
  }
}
```

Let me know if any of that is helpful!